# MVC Page Model's List Items on Submit to use in Post Method

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list that is created and filled with values upon the page loading. When the page is submitted, I need to use those values from the list in the post method.

Is there a way to do that for list items?

For other fields I do this:

```
     < input asp-for="FileID" type="hidden" />
```

But I have this list in the Model:

```
     public List<String> DocumentListing { get; set; }
```

But both of the attempts below do not allow me to see the list items in Controller's Post method on submit

```
int DocumentsCount = Model.DocumentListing.Count();

 for (int i = 0; i < DocumentsCount; i++)
{
    Model.DocumentListing.Add(Model.DocumentListing.ElementAtOrDefault(i));

    <input asp-for="DocumentListing.ElementAtOrDefault(i)" type="hidden">
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#collections),

If you want to accept the list, the request data should be like `DocumentListing[0],DocumentListing[1]...`.

An example below:

```
<form method="post">

    <input asp-for="FileID" type="hidden" />

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DocumentListing.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="DocumentListing[i]" type="text">
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var test = new Test
    {
        FileID = 1,
        DocumentListing = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }
    };

    return View(test);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Test test)
{
        
    return View(test);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This does work. Of course I modified what I actually wanted to make it a list of strings instead of a custom list object. So this doesnt work for custom objects, but it does for what I asked. Im going to make a separate question for custom object lists. Thanks!